# 2007 Ford Explorer - No Start, No sound, No power

Tags: electrical, ford, starting, explorer, ignition-switch

My son's Ford explorer does not start on the first try but when he try's again then it starts. On the first initial start try there is no clicking, no sound like turning over, no dash lights etc. But when he try's again, it starts right up.

What could the problem be?

Comment: Sounds like an ignition switch.  You will need to do some probing with a test light or multimeter to verify if that is the cause or not.

Comment: @jody  It's probably your ignition switch.  Do you know how to use a mutlimeter or a test light?

Answer (score 2):

Based upon the information you've provided it sounds like the issue revolves around the ***ignition switch***.

It's inconsistent in it's operation and seems like it would be the root cause.

If the ignition switch is the issue then part of the steering column and facade around the switch would need to be removed.